# Is there any way to manage mysql users and get a database size in MySQL using Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm currently making a hosting panel but I have some problems with the database management. Is there any way to manage(create/edit permissions/delete) mysql users and get a database size(MB) in MySQL using Laravel Eloquent? Currently using Laravel 8, thank you!

Comment: you can do all that using raw mysql queries

Comment: @Youssef he/she asked about Eloquent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. Eloquent is purely a wrapper around queries for existing databases/users. If you need to do anything else like managing users within mysql you'll have to do it with raw queries.